# django-rest-framework and return dictionary

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm looking for a soultion to receive json response just as dictionary in {} without extra []. Please fine my code below.

in views.py i have:

```
class authTest(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsApiUser,)
    serializer_class = authDistinctSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed

        user = self.request.user
        authz = authDistinctSqlView.objects.filter(emailId=user)

        return authz
```

Next in serializers.py I have:

```
class authSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = authSqlView
        fields = ('countryName', 'courrencyCode', 'countryCode',)


class authDistinctSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    countries = authSerializer(many=True)
    status = serializers.CharField(source='show_auth_status')

    class Meta:
        model = authDistinctSqlView
        fields = ('status', 'emailId', 'region', 'url', 'countries',)
```

and I receiving below result in []
what I should do to receive same result just dict {} without extra top [] ?

```
[

{
    "status": "Authorized",
    "emailId": "user@domain.com",
    "region": "EMEA",
    "url": "127.0.0.1",
    "countries": [
        {
            "countryName": "POLAND",
            "courrencyCode": "PLN",
            "countryCode": "PL"
        }
    ]
}

]
```

Comment: I found that I can use RetrieveAPIView but how I can lookup onto self.request.user ? with no lookup in URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have probably guessed your results are being returned as a list because you are using a `ListAPIView`.

Using a `RetrieveAPIView` you need to replace your `get_queryset` with `get_object`:

```
def get_object(self):
    # Don't need these two lines if you have implemented authentication properly:
    # if not self.request.user:
    #    raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed

    user = self.request.user
    authz = authDistinctSqlView.objects.get(emailId=user.email)

    return authz
```

And it should work, regardless of whether you are trying to extract any values from the URL.

Comment: Thanks Man! This is working for me well. I need to update myself for about diffs btw. get_queryset and get_object to understand why.

Comment: Glad it's working.  Basically if you are writing a list view i.e. a view that returns more than one instance of a model then you use `get_queryset`.  If you are writing a detail view i.e. a view that returns a single object then you use `get_object`.  Obviously you have to use the correct base class (`ListAPIView` or `RetrieveAPIView`) for your view otherwise your method overrides will not get called.

Comment: So. this difference is coming from Django CBV ?

Comment: I'm not sure which CBV views the DRF views are subclasses of, but they do follow the same pattern, i.e. `django.views.generic.ListView` has a `get_queryset()` method for you to override and `django.views.generic.DetailView` has `get_object()`.

Answer (score 0):

use `get` instead of `filter` to get single data response in dictionary format

```
authz = authDistinctSqlView.objects.get(emailId=user) #get instead of filter
```